# Underscore js syntax error in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, underscore.js

I am using the underscore js library (http://underscorejs.org/#filter) for functionality in my app.

Everything works as expected in chrome.  However when I run the same code in IE11 I get an js error in the console

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
File: OptionSrv.js, Line: 197, Column: 62

When I clicked the file to bring me to the error the cursor is placed on the **=>** - is this a red herring or should there be another way of doing this which works in both chrome and IE?

Note if I comment out the line in IE I don't get the console error however this obviously isn't the fix that I need

```
  var group = myOptions.filter(g => g.options.indexOf(option.OptionCode) > -1);
```

Comment: What does this have to do with underscore syntax? The error message you get is pointing at `=>` which is an ES6 arrow function … and **is not used in the example you link to**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 11 does not support arrow functions.

That's the `g => g.options.indexOf(option.OptionCode) > -1` part of your code.

You can use a normal anonymous (or named) function instead here, and it should work fine:

```
var group = myOptions.filter(function(g) {
    g.options.indexOf(option.OptionCode) > -1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

IE11 does not support ES6 syntax. If you want to write ES6 syntax like Arrow functions, you can run your code through a transpiler like Babel.

If you like your client-side code to be compatible with older browsers and you don't care about new syntax, simply use ES5 syntax :)